# PHP displaying values in list mode instead of another cell

Tags: php, html

I'm very near to the expected output, however I'm stuck and need some guidance on the below issues:

I need to group the values in one category and hence needs to be displayed in one cell. Currently, a new column is being created. for example, under objective ->Lead Generation, I wish to create ONLY two columns, one has values -`Male (6.47% cheaper ), Male (15.91% cheaper )` displayed in list mode, and other column should have values `5-54 (6.47% cheaper ),35-44 (15.91% cheaper )`, again displayed in list mode. Currently, for loop is creating one specific column for every value. Attached is the expected output. I used the `explode` function as well to create an array, but not sure how to create the list values as it would probably mess up with the `<td>` of HTML

PHP array generated is like this:

```
array(2) { 

[0]=> array(3) 

{ ["Objective"]=> string(11) "Conversions" 

["Top Performing Targeting Group"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(48) "Female (27.74% cheaper )^25-34 (27.74% cheaper )" [1]=> string(48) "Female (22.52% cheaper )^18-24 (22.52% cheaper )" } 

["Top Performing Placement"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(52) "Mobile Feed (13.53% cheaper)^iPhone (13.53% cheaper)" } }

[1]=> array(3) 

{ ["Objective"]=> string(10) "Page Likes" 
["Top Performing Targeting Group"]=> array(0) { } 
["Top Performing Placement"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(50) "Mobile Feed (1.42% cheaper)^iPhone (1.42% cheaper)" [1]=> string(51) "Mobile Feed (1.71% cheaper)^Android (1.71% cheaper)" } } }
```

PHP Function:

```
  function generateTable2($associative_array){
    echo '<table width="620" class="optimization_table" border="1"  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><thead><tr><th>';
    echo implode('</th><th>', array_keys(current($associative_array)));
    echo '</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
    foreach ($associative_array as $row=>$value){
        echo "<tr>";

        if(is_array($value)) {
            foreach($value as $value2) {
                if(is_array($value2)) {
                    echo "<td><table border='1'  cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tr>";
                    foreach($value2 as $value3) {
                        $values = explode("^", $value3);
                        $value3 = $values[0];
                        $value4 = $values[1];
                        echo "<td>$value3</td>\n";
                        echo "<td>$value4</td>\n";
                    }
                    echo "</tr></table></td>\n";
                }
                else {

                    echo "<td>$value2</td>\n";
                }

            }
        }
        else {
            echo "<td>$value</td>\n";    
        }

        echo "</tr>";

    }
    echo '</tbody></table>';
    }
```

Current Output
[image]

Expected output: ex The colored cell has the multiple values, I want to display them in one cell instead of different column every time 
[image]

Comment: Looks like the expected output is missing from your question.

Comment: just added. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: can someone pls help

Answer (score 0):

It appears that what you want to do is replace

```
echo "<td>$value3</td>\n";
echo "<td>$value4</td>\n";
```

with

```
echo "<td>$value3<br>$value4</td>\n";
```